# Unity - Camera zoom/transform android problem

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The below script is responsible for rotating and zooming (adjusting the cameras transform) the main camera, the rotate works fine and the zoom almost works fine.

Once built to an android device i can smoothly "pinch" zoom in and out in 1 motion, my problem lies when i release the pinch.

if i zoom all the way in then release, then go to zoom back out with a small pinch motion the cameras transform snaps back out to what i assume is the max cameras range, if i have a wide spread touch the camera correctly slowly zooms back out with my fingers position.

Regardless of how the user first performs the pinching motion i would like the camera to always start "zooming" out from its starting position, I assume i need to store a position at the point of the release then start back from there but i cannot figure it out. any help would be great, ta.

```
void LateUpdate()
        {
            if (_target)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    // For single finger touch, detect movement for rotation
                    _velocityX += _xSpeed * Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x * 0.02f;
                    _velocityY += _ySpeed * Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y * 0.02f;
                }
                else if (Input.touchCount == 2)
                {
                    // For two-finger touch, detect pinch for zooming
                    Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
                    Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

                    Vector2 touchDeltaPos = touchZero.position - touchOne.position;
                    float touchDeltaMag = touchDeltaPos.magnitude;

                    _pinchDistances[_pinchFramesIndex] = touchDeltaMag;
                    _pinchFramesIndex = (_pinchFramesIndex + 1) % _pinchFramesCount;

                    float avgPinchDistance = 0.0f;
                    foreach (float distance in _pinchDistances)
                    {
                        avgPinchDistance += distance;
                    }
                    avgPinchDistance /= _pinchFramesCount;

                    float deltaMagnitudeDiff = avgPinchDistance - _pinchDistances[(_pinchFramesIndex - 1 + _pinchFramesCount) % _pinchFramesCount];

                    _distance = Mathf.Clamp(_distance + deltaMagnitudeDiff * _pinchZoomSensitivity, _distanceMin, _distanceMax);
                }
                else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    // For mouse input
                    _velocityX += _xSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _distance * 0.02f;
                    _velocityY += _ySpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 0.02f;
                }

                _rotationYAxis += _velocityX;
                _rotationXAxis -= _velocityY;
                _rotationXAxis = ClampAngle(_rotationXAxis, _yMinLimit, _yMaxLimit);
                Quaternion fromRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
                Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_cameraAngle, _rotationYAxis, 0);
                Quaternion rotation = toRotation;

                // Zooming
                _distance = Mathf.Clamp(_distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * _pinchZoomSensitivity, _distanceMin, _distanceMax);

                Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -_distance);
                Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + _target.position;
                transform.rotation = rotation;
                transform.position = position;
                _velocityX = Mathf.Lerp(_velocityX, 0, Time.deltaTime * _smoothTime);
                _velocityY = Mathf.Lerp(_velocityY, 0, Time.deltaTime * _smoothTime);
            }
        }
```